# Bijection between natural numbers and set of finite rows of natural numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have to construct a bijection between $\Bbb N$ the natural numbers and $\Bbb S$, where $\Bbb S$ is the set of finite rows of natural numbers.

S=$\{(n_0,n_1,...,n_k)|k\in \Bbb N,n_i\in \Bbb N\}$
I did a similar problem here:[bijection between natural numbers and set of strictly growing finite rows](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2518447/bijection-between-natural-numbers-and-set-of-strictly-growing-finite-rows) but can figure it out for this one.

Comment: There are lots of options, but here's a hint: think about prime factorizations.

Comment: do you assume that all elements in a row are different?

Comment: Note that the set of strictly increasing $k$-tuples of natural numbers can easily be mapped bijectively to the set of $k$-tuples of natural numbers, by considering partial sums.

Comment: Lazy comment that might work: all of these can be viewed as decimal representations of Q uniquely, so it embeds into Q.

Answer (score 3):

I will write rows with $[ ~~]$ brackets. (If you also admit an empty row $\emptyset$ you can just extend the bollow definition with $f(\emptyset) := 1$).

Then we can define a bijection $f : \mathbb{S} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}_{>1}$ by
\begin{align}
f([a_1, \dots, a_k]) := p_1^{a_1} \dots p_{k-1}^{a_{k-1}} \cdot p_k^{1 + a_k}
\end{align}
Where $p_k$ is the $k$-th prime. It is then easy to get a bijection $\mathbb{S} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ by combining $f$ with a bijection $\mathbb{N}_{>1} \to \mathbb{N}$.

---

**Proof of Surjectivity:**

Any $n > 1$ has a biggest ($k$-th) prime number $p_k$ with exponent $e > 0$ s.t. $n = x \cdot p_k^e$ and $p_k \not \mid x$.

If $x = 1$ we have
$
f ([\underbrace{0, \dots ,0}_{k-1 \text{ times}},e-1] ) =  p_k^{1 + (e-1)} = x \cdot p_k^e = n
$

If $x > 1$ then we have $x < n$, and therefore by complete induction $x$ has a preimage $[x_1, \dots, x_l]$. Then we have
\begin{align}
 f ( [ x_1 , \dots , 1 + x_l, ~\color{Blue}{0, \dots ,0}, ~e-1 ] )
= p_1^{x_1} \dots  p_l^{1 + x_l} \cdot p_k^{1 + (e-1)} = x \cdot p_k^e = n
\end{align}
Where we need to put $\color{blue}{\text{$(k-l)-1$ zeros}}$ between $(1 + x_l)$ and $(e-1)$ to make sure the latter is the $k$-th entry of the tuple.
Note that we must have $l < k$ since the biggest prime in $n$ was $p_k$ and all primes $p_l$ appearing in $x$ must be smaller. $\Box$

---

**Proof of Injectivity:**

Assume $f([a_1, \dots, a_n]) = f([b_1, \dots, b_m])$, then
$$
 p_1^{a_1} \dots p_n^{1 + a_n} = p_1^{b_1} \dots p_m^{1 + b_m}
$$
where both sides are [prime factorisations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic#Canonical_representation_of_a_positive_integer) of the same number. Since $\color{Red}{\text{said number is bigger then } 1}$, we can conclude $n = m$ and $a_j = b_j$ by the uniqueness of prime factorizations. $\Box$

---

Note that it is in the proof for injectivity, that the (seemingly odd) $+1$ in the power of the last prime number $\color{Red}{\text{plays its crucial role}}$. Without it, the proof would not work.

Answer (score 1):

For all $(n_0,\ldots,n_k) \in \mathbb{S}$ consider the sum $n = \sum_{i=0}^k (n_i+1)$. There are many finite elements of $\mathbb{S}$ that have that sum equal to a fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$. We can order them in the following way

$$ (n_0,\ldots,n_k) \leq (m_0,\ldots,m_h) \Leftrightarrow 
\begin{cases}
k \leq r \\
k=r, n_t < m_t \text{ and } n_i = m_i \forall i < t \text{ for some } t \leq k
\end{cases}
$$ 
It is now clear that we can put the elements of $\mathbb{S}$ in a sequence by considering first all the rows with sum equal to 1, then all the rows with sum equal to 2 and so on...

Answer (score 1):

Take the first $n$ prime numbers $\{ p_k \}_n$ (1 excluded). 
Then
$$
 \pi : \quad  S \mapsto L= \prod_k p_k^{n_k} 
$$
is a bijection by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Comment: I think you need to add a $-1$ after the prime factorization to make sure that 1 gets hit. Also you might consider replacing gcd algorithm by "fundamental theorem of arithmetic". I'm not entirely clear how this follows from the Euclidean algorithm. Other than that looks good.

Comment: Do you mean L-1?

Comment: I mean that in terms of surjectivity I don't see any sequence that would be mapped to 1, unless 0 is allowed to be a natural number, in which case case I don't see anything that would be mapped to zero. I believe if you subtract 1 from the product it becomes bijective, but I haven't explicitly checked.

Comment: Actually no I'm thinking it may not be fixable. If zero is not considered a natural number then numbers that have gaps in their prime factorization don't get hit ($e.g. \ 2*5=10$) because the exponent of 3 will always be positive. If you allow zero then any sequence consisting of only zeros gets sent to 1 and you lose injectivity. This IS the method by which one normally encodes sequences (godel numbering), but its designed to be injective and not necessarily bijective.

Comment: For very large numbers and their long sequences, this method becomes a disaster, because  generates incredibly huge numbers